# replacing the string of the file name and using it in the same shell script

Tags: shell

I have one set of files with naming convention bond_7.LEU.CA.1.dat bond_10.VAL.CB.1.dat..... and have other set of files starting with the string distance rather than bond with the same extension i.e.,distance_7.LEU.CA.1.dat .... and i am trying to  merge corresponding or subsequent lines of files using paste command in shell scripting

I am intending to do
paste bond_7.LEU.CA.1.dat distance_7.LEU.CA.1.dat  > ../raj/angle_dist_7.LEU.CA.dat

I have tried to use for loop and stuck with replacing the string of the file name to access the appropriate file.

Thanks in advance,

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
for FILE in bond* 
do
    paste "$FILE" "${FILE/bond/distance}" > "../raj/${FILE/bond/angle_dist}"
done
```

Is that it?

ps. Such substitutions don't work in pure `sh`. You should to use `bash` or `ksh` or `zsh` or smth like that.

pps. To use it with `sh` replace `"${FILE/bond/distance}"` with

```
`echo $FILE | sed 's/bond/distance/'`
```

Comment: +1: note that although `${FILE/bond/distance}` is non standard, you can use the standard `distance${FILE#bond}` to achieve the same thing.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: it is standard in bash, see [the BASG](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html), search for `${string/substring/replacement}`.

Comment: `standard in bash` is an oxymoron.  It works in bash, and some other shells, but it is not standard bourne shell syntax.